# Python dict.fromkeys return same id element

Tags: python, dictionary

When i do this on python i update all keys in one time.

```
>>> base = {}
>>> keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> base.update(dict.fromkeys(keys, {}))
>>> base.get('a')['d'] = {}
>>> base
{'a': {'d': {}}, 'c': {'d': {}}, 'b': {'d': {}}}
>>> map(id, base.values())
[140536040273352, 140536040273352, 140536040273352]
```

If instead of `.get` i use `[]` operator this not happen:

```
>>> base['a']['d'] = {}
>>> base
{'a': {'d': {}}, 'c': {}, 'b': {}}
```

Why?

Comment: Because that's how `dict.fromkeys` works.

Comment: Python won't clone the dictionary object you passed into `dict.fromkeys()` automatically. All three keys refer to the same dict.

Comment: The question is not why the function or class behaves that way, but rather how would you expect it to work? Have you been surprised by its workflow? If so, think of an alternative API and suggest it on the mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize the value for the new keys as `{}` a new dictionary is created and a reference to this dictionary is becoming the values. There is only one dictionary and so if you change one, you will change "all".

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with both Python 2.7.6 and 3.4.3. I get the same answer when either `get('a')` or `['a']` is used. Appreciate if you can verify this at your end. Python does object reuse. Thus, `dict.fromkeys()` reuses the same empty `dict` is to initialize. To make each one a separate object, you can do this:

```
base.update(zip(keys, ({} for _ in keys)))
```